# Why can't i put these variables in global scope? It only works in local.

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

The code below will write in FirstName LastName is X years old. However, if I want to pull out the jquery variables val() variables in the button click and make them global, it doesn't work. I am not sure why.

```
function Household (firstName, lastName, age){


  var _list = {
      "_fname": firstName,
      "_lname": lastName,
      "_age": age
  };

this.addPerson = function () {

    var writeIn = _list._fname + " " + _list._lname + " is " + _list._age + " years old.";

    return writeIn;
 }

}



$('#btnSub').click(function(){

  var _getFName = $('#enterFName').val();
  var _getLName = $('#enterLName').val();
  var _getAge = $('#enterAge').val();

  var nuHouse = new Household (_getFName, _getLName, _getAge);

  var newNuHouse = nuHouse.addPerson();

  $('#insertAnswer').html(newNuHouse);

});
```

Why doesn't this work? I want to make the values global so I can access them via other button clicks.

```
function Household (firstName, lastName, age){


var _list = {
    "_fname": firstName,
    "_lname": lastName,
    "_age": age
};

this.addPerson = function () {

    var writeIn = _list._fname + " " + _list._lname + " is " + _list._age + " years old.";

    return writeIn;
}

}

var _getFName = $('#enterFName').val();
var _getLName = $('#enterLName').val();
var _getAge = $('#enterAge').val();

var nuHouse = new Household (_getFName, _getLName, _getAge);


$('#btnSub').click(function(){

   var newNuHouse = nuHouse.addPerson();

   $('#insertAnswer').html(newNuHouse);

});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/m78r173j/

Comment: Not able to replicate it.See this demo
https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/mvwr4cq6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom code does not work because you're getting the value at the time of the script execution, not when the button is clicked.

You can continue to declare the variables globally but move the assignment to the event listener, however it is generally beneficial to reduce the number of globals.  If you let us know how you intend to use the values we may be able to suggest a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need update value of these variable on event click.
Because at first pageload, these input don't have any value.

```
var _getFName;
var _getLName;
var _getAge;

var nuHouse;


$('#btnSub').click(function(){
   _getFName = $('#enterFName').val();
   _getLName = $('#enterLName').val();
   _getAge = $('#enterAge').val();

   nuHouse = new Household (_getFName, _getLName, _getAge);
   var newNuHouse = nuHouse.addPerson();

   $('#insertAnswer').html(newNuHouse);

});
```